# how to manage mulitple users for processing in linux server?

Tags: server, users

I am a computational student, and we have three servers, each with 48 processors and multiple users.
here is what I want to do. I want a system in which each user has a specific number of processors and processes that runs above server capacity goes into the queue. for example, when we have all 48 processors occupied new ones are pending. I'm new to Linux so I will be grateful for explanations with details.

Comment: This should do the job, but I will **not** give a running solution in detail: https://slurm.schedmd.com/

Comment: Without slurm solution, any idea?

Comment: If you won't accept certain solutions, please say so in your question above. Don't waste folks' time writing answers that you will reject.

Answer (score 0):

This question is slightly similar to [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/298589/how-to-allocate-a-process-specific-amount-of-cpu-power). The easiest way to "partition" your system's resources is to use containers. I assume that your using Ubuntu, so I'd recommend to use LXD to create containers.

In short containers are isolated spaces to execute your application.

Regarding the queuing that's not possible with LXD, you have to manually create and delete the containers when they are no longer required.

Here is the [documentation for LXD](https://linuxcontainers.org/lxd/getting-started-cli/)